# Hibernate Annotation Mapping for Parent/Child Relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, mapping

I'm having problems mapping ManyToOne from a Parent to Child relationship.  The OneToMany collection populates lazily fine.  However, the inverse to a single entity, does not.

I have a table of Server instances, which is immutable.

When I create a List of Servers, it populates the Collection of Requests that a Server has assigned to it without problems.

When I add a new Request, and select the Server preferred from a dropdown, saveOrUpdate, (or even tried load, and get) it does not populate the Server property in the Request instance.

Server.java

```
public class Server {

    private int serverId;
    private List<Request> requests;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="server", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Request> getRequests() {
      return requests;
    }
}
```

Request.java

```
public class Request {

    private int requestId;
    private int server_serverId; // foreign key to Server.serverId
    private Server server;
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="server_serverId", nullable=false, updatable=false, insertable=false}
    @ForeignKey(name="server_serverId", inverseName="serverId") // Don't think this really does anything
    public Server getServer() {
      return server;
    }
}
```

add.jsp (Add Request form)

```
...

<form:select id="preferred-server" path="server.serverId">
    <c:forEach items="${servers}" var="server">
        <form:option value="${server.serverId}">${server.serverName}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>

...
```

AddRequestController.java

```
public class AddRequestController extends SimpleFormController {
  ...
  @Override
  protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {

    Request request = (Request)command;

    try {
        logger.info("BEFORE SAVE, request.server = " + request.getServer());
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        logger.error("onSubmit() caught NPE: " + npe);
    }

    // Would rather not do these next two lines.  Would prefer to saveOrUpdate
    // Request, and have it populate server property via server_serverId foreign key.
    //Server server = serverDao.loadByServerId(request.getServer_serverId());
    //request.setServer(server);
    //Added this instead, which calls getHibernateTemplate().refresh(server, LockMode.READ)
    serverDao.refreshServer(request.getServer());

    requestDao.addRequest(request); // calls getHibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(request)

    try {
        logger.info("AFTER SAVE, request.server = " + request.getServer());
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        logger.error("onSubmit() caught NPE: " + npe);
    }        

    return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView(), "request", request);
  }
}
```

I've tried virtually every combination of Annotation mapping I could find online, and this is the setup that works with fetching a Collection of Requests.

Now, of course, I can get my Request command object from the SimpleFormController, load the Server object based on what the user selects, and persist it that way--but that's not the point of relationship mapping, now is it?

Any suggestions? Let me know if you require any other code.

Using: Spring 2.5, Hibernate 3.2.5, Sybase DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Request` is the owning side, so you need to add the server to the request, i.e. call `setServer()`. The `server` field is the one responsible for the corresponding column in your database.

It is not sufficient to add the request to the list since that is just the inverse mapping. If you'd set the server in the request and then reload the server from the db, the request should be automatically added to the list (although you'd normally not do that but manually add the server to the list as well).

Thus the Request should look like this:

```
public class Request {

 private int requestId;
 //I don't see any need for this
 //private int server_serverId; // foreign key to Server.serverId
 private Server server;
 ...
 @ManyToOne ( fetch=FetchType.LAZY ) //employ lazy loading, you can put that on @OneToMany too
 @JoinColumn( name="server_serverId", nullable=false }
 public Server getServer() {
  return server;
 }
}
```

Comment: I believe I tried that setup, but I will again.  The thing is, I'd like to be able to just select Request(s) and have the server property populated automatically through Hibernate mapping.  So, the server_serverId foreign key ID would be necessary in order to map from a Request (since the server object is purely for ORM and is not a column in the database) to a Server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point, but just using server should be sufficient, sinc the foreign key to the server's id should be mapped to column `server_serverId` in the request table anyway. Note that you might also want to employ lazy loading, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I updated my question with my SimpleFormController implementation.

Comment: As to your comment in that implementation: you could of course use a `serverId` column and assign the server's id. In that case you would then indeed add the `updatable=false, insertable=false` and in the end have two fields map to one column. Note that you should also be able to create a detached server entity, set the id and call `setServer()`. In that case you should make sure not to cascade anything to server when saving the request. I'd have to check that second aproach though (or you could do it), so don't rely on that.

Comment: Yup, knew I had to have updatable and insertable to false from earlier errors:
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Request column: server_serverId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
Going to try with a detached Server also, but would just love for it to populate on update. Hmmm...

Comment: @Chris Note that by just setting the serverId to the request you might have to refresh the request entity from the database in order to get the server field populated with at least a proxy entity. If you don't do this it might still be null.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  What if I want to SELECT a single or collection of Request object(s)--should the Server field be automatically populated based on the JoinColumn I specified? That's what I ultimately am looking for.  If not, is there a way to do this differently? Thanks.

Comment: @Chris The server should just be populated when reading from the database. Note that you might have to do a fetch join in order to prevent additional selects when accesing the server, since lazy loading normally first sets server to a proxy which will cause the Server entity to be loaded if not already in some cache (mostly the transaction's first level cache).

Comment: @Thomas: So wouldn't I just set fetchType to FetchType.EAGER for the fetch Join (which I believe is the default).  Or do you think a custom query may be necessary for populating the Server object?

Comment: @Chris You don't need a custom query and it should work with FetchType.LAZY. The difference is that for FetchType.LAZY a subselect might be issued if you access the server object if it is not already loaded ( hence the fetch join) whereas FetchType.EAGER would cause the server to **always**  be loaded, whether you need it or not.

Comment: Yeah, it will most likely be loaded, since the list of Servers is fetched for the New Request form. Any other suggestions for optimizing this flow, or do you think the structure is ok?

Comment: Without knowing more the structure seems to be ok. You might just enable SQL output for Hibernate to see which statements are actually executed. If you see statements that you think you don't need (something you don't need is getting loaded) you might try further optimization.

Comment: I think I finally understand what I was doing wrong--can't believe I didn't think of it initially! I should bind the form drop down to the server.serverId property in Request--not to server_serverId property.  Now I see why you said I don't need it.  I'll still have the column, defining the Join column as the actual column name, and using the server property to map that should work exactly as I need.  This way, I won't need to explicitly create a new Server instance when I save the Request--I can just setServer(new Server()) in my base constructor in Request.  Will let you know of results.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm having trouble getting the save to work now, after removing the server_serverId property from my Request class.  How can I get the server property in Request to insert to the Request table on save? You mentioned I didn't need the foreign key property in my class--do you know how to implement this? Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on what doesn't work/the exceptions you get? If you don't use the server_serverId property you should not use the updatable = false etc. but I assume you do that already. Besides that you should be fine by setting the server to a new detached server instance, set that server's id to the correct one and save without cascading. In order to check whether the problem lies with that association you might first get the correct server entity and set it to the request and see if that works now. If not, your problems are somewhere else.

Comment: It worked fine when I created the detached Server in the onSubmit function, but I'm trying to bind to the Server.serverId instance through the Form, but having "dirty" errors.  I'll get the specifics when I pull the app up again.

Comment: I'm getting "reassociated object has dirty collection reference (or an array)" error.  I'm sure it's related to me fetching a List of Servers in the beginning, and trying to saveOrUpdate Request with a Server that was already pulled into the List.  However, Server should never actually be "dirty"--as it's read-only as far as this application is concerned.  Now, we know that loading the Server and setting it to the Request after the form is submitted works--but, that was when I used server_serverId property.  Now, I want to bind my form value to the actual Server property in Request.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow "clean" the dirty object, or make it so it is never dirty? Or will I have to go the "un-pretty" way and just re-load my Server object after Form submission? Let me know if you think I should start a new Question at this point, lol.  Thanks.

Comment: You could try and call `EntityManager.refresh()` on the entity. Other than that, you might actually start a new question since this series of comments is getting quite long and others aren't thus likely follow it ;)

Comment: Haha, funny you should suggest that--I just tried that last night, and it did work, but I noticed it did do a SELECT.  Shouldn't it just get it from cache since I fetched a List of Server objects earlier on? Or since it's a new session, it needs to go to the DB again.

Comment: No, according to the JavaDoc `refresh()` loads from the DB, but if you want to get the object from the cache you should try `EntityManager.findById()` which first queries the cache and then looks up the object from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Thomas.  If anything else comes up, I'll create a new Question, as this one has gone on long enough :)